# Laravel with Salesforce Token

Tags: security-token

Laravel 4.2 Library: `"davispeixoto/laravel-salesforce": "2.0.*"`

```
<?php
return array(

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Your Salesforce credentials
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    |
    */

//    sandbox
    'username' => 'sample@gmail.com',
    'password' => '*****',
    'token' => '',
    'wsdl' => app_path() . '/wsdl/enterprise.sandbox.wsdl.xml',
);
```

I used to login username and password in my salesforce developers account.
I've been there, but I can't see where the token is. Where is it?

Answer (score 1):

You get your security token by email. It's optional if your IP address is white listed. If you've lost your token, login through the browser, and go to My Settings, Personal Settings, Reset Security Token. You'll get a new one by email.